# apache .htacces configuration

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm following the symfony create your own mvc tutorial and I'm at a loss as to how to configure my apache server to point to the web directory.

Following the tutorial. My file structure has pages in the src folder, composer in the vendor folder and my front.php in the web folder with the associated routes. If I go to web/front.php all works fine.

How do I configure the .htaccess file?

Comment: Well, how do you want your URL to look like? From that you can then derive how to setup your server side.

Comment: Running on my xampp server, just localhost/projectname/"variable"

Answer (score 0):

Generally it is recommended not to use dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"), but to place rewriting rules inside the host configuration itself (performance and maintainability reasons). You will find tons of examples for such internal rewritings here on SO, your best starting point to read into that however certainly is the official documentation. It comes with great examples: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

This is a simple example that should point you into the right direction:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?projectname/(.*)/?$ /web/front.php?variable=$1 [L]
```

That will take care to internally rewrite the request so that you can access the variable value as `$_GET['variable']`.

The example uses a pattern that will work likewise in dynamic configuration files (".htaccess") and in the real http servers host configuration. If you really want to use dynamic files, then you also need to enable their interpretation by means of the `AllowOverride` directive. Again take a look at the official documentation for that: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride